# ZF2 how to set a folder of uploaded files?

Tags: file, upload, zend-framework2, directory

I have a form of uploading a file and everything works. I just need to set the folder into which files will be thrown.

My files: http://wklej.org/id/1756722/

Answer (score 0):

Just add filter RenameUpload to Your FilesFilter:

```
Form/FilesFilter:

<?php

namespace DynamicAppModuleFiles\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class FilesFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->add(array(
            'name'=> 'upload',
            'required'=> true,
            'validators' => array(
                array('name'=>'NotEmpty')
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'File/RenameUpload',
                    'options' => array(
                        'target' => 'path/to store/files'
                    )
                )
            )
        ));

    }

}
```

More options you can find here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.file.html#renameupload

EDIT:

Also make sure that you're calling `$form->getInputFilter()->getValues();` after `$form->isValid()`

Comment: when i click on add new file, i have this error:
Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for RenameUpload

Comment: Ok, i've edited my answer, try to use File/RenameUpload for filter name

Comment: all in the process, but I do not see the file on the ftp server. ('target' => './data/uploads',)

Comment: make sure that script has permission to write there

Comment: Jak dodaję to co napisałeś to otrzymuję taki błąd: File './uploads' could not be renamed. It already exists.